# Close md-menu from controller

Tags: angularjs, material-design

I have a md-menu item on my page and I want to be able to close it from a function in my controller.

I think the md-menu directive has a listener that can catch an event trough a broadcast but I can't find anything like that in the material design docs.

Something like this:

```
this.$rootScope.$broadcast('$mdCloseAllMenus);
```

This obviously doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Not aware of any listeners, however you should use the `$mdMenu`. Inject it into your controller. From there you should call

`$mdMenu.hide(null, { closeAll: true });`

Comment: Thanks, just found this as well. I think the `.hide()` function does a `$broadcast` and all mdMenu instances catch it and "close" themself. That's what I meant :)